# Abstract Class Infere type of Abstract Function on Implementation

Tags: typescript, generics, abstract-class, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Hello im trying to make an abstract generic Class with 1 generic type T ,
And it contains an abstract generic function with type K, is it now possible to infer its type when the function gets implemented?
Here an Example what i want to archieve

```
interface foo {
  id: number;
  otherVal: number;
  someVal: number;
}

interface fooUpdate {
  id: number;
  someVal: number
}


export abstract class BasicState<T> { 
  entities: T[] = []

  abstract apiPatchOne<K>(updateDto: K): T

  editOneAndDoStuff<K>(updateDto: K):T {
    // Does Something
    const response = this.apiPatchOne(updateDto);
    //Do More Stuff
    return response
  }
}

class implemented extends BasicState<foo> {

  apiPatchOne(updateDto: fooUpdate) {
      const something: foo = {id: 1, otherVal: 2, someVal: 3}
      return something
  }
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=32&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAhgezcg3gKGf5YAEwC5kQBXAWwCNoBuPAtMAC2gDU4AbMy2hk3wBnNFQhde5anSiMAvjhyhIsRCnRoAqgAcicSNiGFS0gXOOjxkvjOg5FSiAA8daKGGRwawsFESeCNxwwsLIAEIhwAgAymAGEAA8ACoAfNjIxhDgwGDAEMJkyQDaALrIALzIZUoEXj5+AV46wAAKBgisAPIgSQDSqQAUFHoJACJgaGR9AJRFtQQQRLk9EACCIERjaHEUMDCJA8OjkBNTyLMkyUZ1dQD0d8jbBcgxYhBsoADmxnUIaCBfMgoAU3ICUFVPsIAHRwFrtMCdVbHfSnSYzRi3AgPbbIACy7hQu32vwIILAFCgIGBoIBwggTEUjiCITCwCoOm4EHE4CWyBckE2YUiwmicQSiU06VwxjhbQ63V6KPGkzIml0qIgMxuWOQ-0BnisH1Y3zVGEq2GIZAAjAAaZAsdhQGzIABM9qNLoAzIpdTSKVTkEbPiAfnUmUA

Is this even possible ?

Comment: As written, you want two generic type parameters in your class, not one.  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NdjovW).  A generic method like `apiPatchOne<U>(updateDto: U): T` means that the *caller* can choose `U`, not the *implementer*.  Move the generic type parameter out of the methods and into the class and it will work.  Does that meet your needs or am I missing something?

Comment: Sadly it wont work to add the type at the class :/

The example is pretty simple and basic but in my Project it has to be the function that infers the type :/.

To be more Precise the implementation of apiPatchOne<U>(updateDto: U): T

should also infere the type of  editOneAndDoStuff<U>(updateDto: U):T
I thought it could be possible becaus editOneAndDoStuff calls apiPatchOne

atleast this would be the best case

Comment: A note about naming conventions: object type names are conventionally written in UpperPascalCase, so you should consider changing to `Foo`, `FooUpdate`, and `Implemented`; the generic type parameter `K` is almost exclusively used to represent the type of an object *key*; since you are not referring to such a type, you should consider changing it to something more neutral; after `T`, it is conventional to use `U`.

Comment: Please demonstrate with a [mre] a situation in which it has to be the function that infers the type, inside the question itself.  Generic functions and methods simply do not work the way you want, and without a motivating example the only possible solution is to move the scope of the type parameter out of the call signatures and into the class.  You say it won't work to add the type to the class; can you show that?

Comment: I worded it wrong it would work at Class Level but its not feasible, most of the time many api calls share the same Type in the implementation but thats not allways the case ( and there are a lot) , the alternative is to do declare for every api call another generic and allways write all in the class .
Would be simpler to declare the type in the implementation of the function (the function has to be implemented anyways...)
but yea when it wont work than it wont work ..^^.

Comment: I mean, you can make generic *defaults*, like `BasicState<T, U=T, V=U, W=V>` so that `BasicState<A>` is equivalent to `BasicState<A, A, A, A>` and `BasicState<A, B>` is equivalent to `BasicState<A, B, B, B>` and you don't have to write it all out manually.  But without a [mre] of the feasibility issue you're talking I can't say anything with certainty.  So at this point, what would you like to see regarding an answer to the question?  As asked, the answer is "put your second type parameter in the class`; if you want a different suggestion, you should probably edit the question. Let me know!